# Simple left shifting with C#

Tags: c#, bit-shift

I convert two strings from ASCII hex to byte

```
byte[] address = new byte[2];
int fullAddress;

address[0] = Convert.ToByte(stringZero, 16);
address[1] = Convert.ToByte(stringOne, 16);

fullAddress = (address[0] << 0xFFFF);
fullAddress |= address[1];
```

This yields a wrong output on the high niblle of `fullAddress`, low nibble is always correct. How should this be done correctly?

EDIT: The address should be a 32 bit value. 
E.g,

```
StringZero = 0x01
StringOne = 0x02
fullAddress = 0x0102
```

Comment: Can you share the expect and actual outputs?

Comment: Ok so the shift should be by 8 then. That's actually a 16bit value btw.

Comment: @harold so it is the LSB which is shifted?

Comment: Well, shifting it left means it goes towards more significant bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are shifting left by 0xFFFF, or 65535. The right hand operand of the left shift (<<) operator is the number of bits to shift. I think you meant 4.

```
fullAddress = (address[0] << 4);
fullAddress |= address[1];
```

Comment: I am sorry for not explaining this further, but I expect a 32 bit value as a result. See updated question

Comment: Replace the '4' with an '8' in @Gusdor's example

Comment: Yeh, int should have told me that it was 32bit. Sorry about that. FOOLISH GUSDOR.